# Why does my iMac have 4 drives

Tags: hard-drive, imac, ssd, fusion-drive

I have a 2017 iMac with fusiondrive, where the drive always have been really slow. I then got my 1TB HDD replaced with a SSD, but still the same. I also seems I have four drives now after I had to reinstall a couple of times after the new harddrive.
Any clues how to remove "copy-drives"?

[image: M HD 2 + 3 seems like copies of the real HD]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *28.0 GB    disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk2⁩         27.7 GB    disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk2⁩         1000.0 GB  disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.0 TB     disk2
                                 Physical Stores disk1s2, disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨M HD 2⁩                  1.0 MB     disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 412.0 MB   disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.1 GB     disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 MB     disk2s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨M HD 3⁩                  974.8 KB   disk2s5
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨M HD 4⁩                  730.5 GB   disk2s7
   7:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            15.2 GB    disk2s8
   8:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.2 GB    disk2s8s1

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk3
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS ⁨Extreme Pro⁩             2.0 TB     disk3s2
```

Comment: @DavidAnderson This might need your expertise.